# Unique items in a list and put (-) on the removed one -- Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have the following list.

```
my_list = ['20/20',  '30/30',  '20/80',  '120/120',  '120/140',  '165/165', '30/170',  '165/175']
```

I would like to remove any duplication and would like to keep unique items on the list, keep track of them by converting the dictionary, and put `(-/ or /-)` on the removed duplicate items.

For example, 20/20 should change to 20 and put in the dictionary as `{'20/20':20/-}`, for `'30/30'` change to 30 and put it in the dictionary as `{'30/30': 30/-}`, BUT for `'20/80'` it shouldn't be 20 because I have 20 in a dictionary before so it should be 80 and put it in the dictionary as `{'20/80':-/80}`. The same procedure works for the rest of lists.

My expected result seems like the following dictionary.

```
my_dict = {'20/20':20/-, '30/30': 30/-,  '20/80':-/80,  '120/120':120/-, '120/140':-/140,  '165/165': 165/-,  '30/170': -/170,  '165/175':-/175}
```

I have this implementation but couldn't put `-/ or /-`.

```
my_dict1 = dict((elem, elem.split('/')[0]) for elem in my_list)

my_dict2 = dict((elem, elem.split('/')[1]) for elem in my_list)
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I dont see any relevance for the [tag:pandas] tag ... why add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
my_list = ['20/20',  '30/30',  '20/80',  '120/120',  '120/140',  '165/165', '30/170',  '165/175']
my_new_dict = {}
for i in my_list: 
    temp = i.split('/')
    if((temp[0] > temp[1]) | (temp[0] == temp[1])):
        my_new_dict[i] = str(temp[0])+'/-'
    elif(temp[1] > temp[0]):
        my_new_dict[i] = '-/'+str(temp[1])

print(my_new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the expected output using the following codes:

```
my_list = ['20/20',  '30/30',  '20/80',  '120/120',  '120/140',  '165/165', '30/170',  '165/175']

my_dict1={}
mark={}
for data in my_list:
    x,y=data.split('/')
    #print(x,y)
    if(x==y):
        mark[x]=1
        my_dict1[data]=x+"/-"
    else:
        if(x in mark):
            my_dict1[data]="/-"+y
            mark[y]=1
        elif(y in mark):
            my_dict1[data]=x+"/-"
            mark[x]=1

print(my_dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `set` to keep track of which element you already encountered, and replace them with a `-`, like this:

**EDIT:** using `or` trick to add elems to set within a single expression (lambda), and 2 helper lambdas to solve with a single dict comprehension:

```py
my_list = ['20/20',  '30/30',  '20/80',  '120/120',  '120/140',  '165/165', '30/170',  '165/175']

used = set() # empty set
process_num = lambda num: '-' if num in used or used.add(num) else num
process_elem = lambda pair: '/'.join(map(process_num, pair.split('/')))
my_dict = {elem: process_elem(elem) for elem in my_list}

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'20/20': '20/-', '30/30': '30/-', '20/80': '-/80', '120/120': '120/-', '120/140': '-/140', '165/165': '165/-', '30/170': '-/170', '165/175': '-/175'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This delivers the wanted result, although it gets slower the more elements you add:

```
my_list = ['20/20',  '30/30',  '20/80',  '120/120',  '120/140',  '165/165', '30/170',  '165/175']

d = {}
for item in my_list:
    key1, key2 = item.split("/")
    # quits searching as soon as the first key is found
    ks = any( k for k in d.keys() if k.startswith(f"{key1}/"))
    v = f"{key1}/-" if not ks else f"-/{key2}"
    d[item] = v

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'20/20': '20/-', '30/30': '30/-', '20/80': '-/80', 
 '120/120': '120/-', '120/140': '-/140', '165/165': '165/-', 
 '30/170': '-/170', '165/175': '-/175'}
```